# Run a program in the background, put it in the system tray

Tags: c++, qt, background-process, system-tray

I'm using Qt and I want my program to be able to go in the system tray, but also to be displayed as a window.

For example: I launch my program, it opens a window, ..., I close the window but the program doesn't close, it is still in the background. Then I can reopen the window through the icon created in the system tray.

I know how to create the icon using QSystemTrayIcon and to create a menu when right-clicking on the icon, and launch events through the menu. Yet I don't know how to do so that when I close my program's window, the program remains opened in the background.

To illustrate my point, it would be the same functionment as Steam.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly implement a "minimize to tray" function in Qt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332257/how-do-i-properly-implement-a-minimize-to-tray-function-in-qt)

Comment: @Torbjörn it's not an exact duplicate as "minimizing" and "closing" need to be handled slightly differently

Comment: @m.s. I see. Then, sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 5):

You need to reimplement `QWidget::closeEvent`, hide the window and **ignore** the `QCloseEvent`.

This is explained in detail in the [Qt System Tray Icon Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-systray-example.html), here is the most interesting part:

```
void Window::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    if (trayIcon->isVisible()) {
        hide();
        event->ignore();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that when I call the hide method from my MainWindow class it doesn't hide the window even if I call it using `this` ; it only works if I call hide from the main function where I can't really get the event

Comment: @Urefeu you should ask a new question containing a [mcve]

Comment: I will, I can't try the solution right now. Besides, when I call `hide()`, it doesn't remove the icon of the program from the taskbar, does it?

Comment: @Urefeu you might also try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6094872/678093

Comment: @Urefeu regarding the taskbar have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4056292/678093